# Does the end user need Skype for business package?

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

For this sample  https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-android-app-sdk-samples I've seen I need to download the Skype business SDK, that means the API which I am going to develop will be available only  for Skype for business?

I need the guest functionality because I want to allow people to speak to each other without being friends. If you have any other suggestion i would be glad to listen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that SDK enables your mobile application to use Skype for Business for communications. You can find SDK docs there: http://aka.ms/skypeappsdk. Guest meeting join workflow is described there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/embedskypeb2ccomms. Check if it matches your requirements.

Basically, it's not 'everybody is guest'. An organization arranges a meeting between its member (being an authenticated user) and its customer that can connect anonymously with a mobile application.